# Determination of functional dependence

Tags: partial-differential-equations, jacobian

How in general can we find a functional relationship between two functions

$$ u(x,y) ~, v(x,y)~$$

when  Jacobian

$$\begin{vmatrix} u_x & u_y \\  v_x & v_y \end{vmatrix}$$

vanishes? i.e., what pde/ode can be used to find the dependence or link equation?

How does it change for three functions and three variables?

Appreciate all help.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151649/discussion-on-question-by-narasimham-determination-of-functional-dependence); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.